# Load Partial View when document is ready

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views

I'm trying to populate one of my unordered list () with items from my DB automatically just as the page has finished loading up. What I need to know is how to get the items. I don't think anything is wrong with the Controller and PartialView. All I need is how to call it from the index page.

The Following code is from the index page:

```
<div class="contentRight">
            <span class="contentRightHeader">Most Followed Questions ·</span><span class="contentRightViewAll"> View all</span>
            <ul>
                <!--<li>Why do we drink and whats the effects on the body</li>
                <li>Why do we drink and whats the effects on the body</li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This code is from the controller:

```
public PartialViewResult _ListMostFollowedQuestions()
    {
        QuestionManager qman = new QuestionManager();
        ViewBag.Questions = qman.ListMostFollowedQuestions(3);
        return PartialView("_ListMostFollowedQuestions");
    }
```

And lastly from my partialView:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Questions)
{
@item.Topic Deadline:
    @item.Deadline      
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try using `Ajax` to load your list after loading `index` page

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in two ways first in your partial view construct the html and call it inside the ul like

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Questions)
{
"<li>"+@item.Topic Deadline:@item.Deadline+"</li>"
}
```

and in

```
<div class="contentRight">
            <span class="contentRightHeader">Most Followed Questions ·</span><span class="contentRightViewAll"> View all</span>
            <ul>
               @Html.RenderPartial("_ListMostFollowedQuestions")
            </ul>
        </div>
```

the second way is the `ajax` way in your index page

```
$(function(){

$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'/path/to/partial',
dataType:'html',
success:function(data){
$("span.contentRightHeader ul").append(data);
}

});

});
```